# MySQL - Multiple tables results into column(kind of full outer join)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like below.

#### T1

```
id, count
1, 10
2, 20
3, 30
```

#### T2

```
id, status
1, 100
2, 200
3, 300
4, 400
```

#### T3

```
id, refresh
2, 2000
3, 3000
```

I want to convert all these table's 2nd columns into one result set.

```
id, count, status, refresh
1,   10,   100,    NULL
2,   20,   200,    2000
3,   30,   300,    3000
4,   NULL, 400,    NULL
```

Im not sure still full outer join supports this format. Any better way to do this?

### Answer:

Since its closed, so posting the answer here:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.id, T2.id , T3.id), T1.count,T2.status,T3.refresh
FROM T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2  USING (id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN T3  USING (id)
UNION 
SELECT COALESCE(T1.id, T2.id , T3.id), T1.count,T2.status,T3.refresh
FROM T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN T1  USING (id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN T3  USING (id)
UNION 
SELECT COALESCE(T1.id, T2.id , T3.id), T1.count,T2.status,T3.refresh
FROM T3 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T1  USING (id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2  USING (id)
```

Comment: This is exactly what full outer join is for. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have it. I've linked to a question that says how to emulate it. You just have to do it multiple times because you have more than 2 tables.

Comment: in your case this has nothing to do with fulloouter join as long as you know that T" has all id you can make https://dbfiddle.uk/5d0N_wHq  only when you know that all the tables have different id you need a full outer join

Comment: It worked like a charm, but on T3 when I have one more row like `5, 5000`, its not showing

Comment: use a Right JOIN ON T3, or you must implemented the full join as Barmar posted also don't Forget `COALAESCE$(T1.id,T3.id)`to get all ids